# How to sync follower with leader in JMeter

Tags: performance, if-statement, jmeter, controller, performance-testing

I am executing the script where have leader and follower concept. I recorded the script leader in one thread group (only 1 leader) and script for follower in another thread group ( 50 followers) in same test plan.

In the application have scenario where when leader pushed the screen then followers screens gets navigate automatically.

I have to create same scenario using JMeter script, that when leader push the screen follower api's get executed after the leader.

I used the logics are below but not worked with that:

1. Used the IF controller at follower end for that particular transaction controller and json extractor to extract value from leader. Added condition in follower.
2. Similarly tried with While controller but is also not worked.

Could you provide solution for this?

Could you provide solution for this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzYWz.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp84j.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the followers to "wait" until the leader does something the easiest way is going for [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#comm)

There is [SynchronizationExample.jmx](https://jmeter-plugins.org/editor/?utm_source=jpgc&utm_medium=openurl&utm_campaign=examples#/img/examples/SynchronizationExample.jmx) test plan which waits until the cookie becomes available in FIFO queue and then executes authenticated request.

You should be able to easily adopt it to your test scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. We tried this solution also but still not working with this.